# How do I switch this script from INSERT to UPDATE

Tags: php, sql-update, insert-update

I would like to change this to UPDATE... Can someone please write the script for me... I've tried for a couple of days with no success. Thank you for your help!

```
$query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl (images_id, `images_path`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$target_path."')";
```

Comment: Please add your question body before your code and describe what is the problem. Please read this before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure why your not aware on how to update an sql if you knew how to insert.. Is this for your homework??
 anyway here is a script on how to update it just modify it to your need. On SO we dont spoon feed everything. We give ideas the rest we find ourselves

```
$query_upload="UPDATE images_tbl SET images_id = ".$your_image_id." images_path = ".$your_target_path.";
```

Comment: Thank you... I have no training at all... everything is self taught... I think... WHERE images_id=".$_SESSION['user_id'].";     ... goes on the end!

Comment: well if this worked might as well choose this as an accepted answer

Comment: I'm still working on it... trying to figure out the WHERE... thank you for helping me with this.... It's for a website of were I help high school athletes with additional recruiting exposure. This particular script is for uploading their profile image to their personal profile.  Right now I have....  $query_upload="UPDATE images_tbl SET images_id = '.$images_id.', images_path = '$target_path' WHERE images_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";   .... but no user_id is showing in the database.

Comment: but does the images_id has data?

Comment: there is no data...

Comment: if a database has no data then there is no way in hell that you can update it..

Comment: images_id int(10)   auto_increment .... but the user data is not showing up...

Comment: i believe thats the structure not the data.. Your database is empty try to do a `SELECT * FROM $tablename`  check if there are data inside that table

Comment: ooppss... I'm not exactly sure where to add the SELECT * FROM $tablename ... but when I put in INSERT .... the database populates but I need it to update instead. I'm working on the SELECT * FROM

Comment: The images_id populates as 0 instead of the user's id number

Comment: Still nothing after adding the select * from ... but there are no errors showing   ... $query_upload="UPDATE images_tbl SET images_id = '".$images_id."', images_path = '".$target_path."' WHERE images_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
$query="select * from images_id WHERE images_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";

Comment: what I mean is do a separate `SELECT` statement to check if you have data inside your tables

Comment: basically you need to insert data 1st on your table before you can update it

Comment: Thank you...it's working perfect... I used... $query_upload="UPDATE users SET id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' , images_path = '".$target_path."' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";

Comment: thats good to hear did this answer helped you? if yes please do marked it as accepted answer

Comment: How or where do I go to mark it as accepted ....I'm very new on this website

Comment: its inlined with my answer look for the check mark on the left side of my answer post